# How do you prevent an insert statement timing out?

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, insert-statement

I have a page where I have cleared the white space but have a feeling that things are not working correctly because it times out. Any solution on how to prevent this.

Comment: Define "I have cleared white space."  What part is actually timing out?  Narrow down the changes you've made and what part is actually failing.  Is it really failing in a SQL statement?  What did you change in order to cause this?  We can help identify problems in code you show us, if you can describe the problems in detail and do some debugging.  But "I changed my code and now it's broken" isn't really a problem description.

Comment: What has happened is I try to do a large insert statement that is within a foreach loop which can at times contain up to 500 items that need inserting. After about 70 have inserted correctly the insert stops working of sorts. All the code is correct as I have done extensive testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit my.cnf (the MySQL configuration file).

```
 vi /etc/my.cnf
```

Locate the timeout configuration and adjust it to fit your server.
ex:

```
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
```

restart server